# How can i get link path if i want include another folder

Tags: php

I want to know that how can i give include path of another folder.

For example, i have a project named test folder. In test folder has one folder which is assets folder and index.php file. In assets folder has two folder which are include and xyz folder. In include folder has two file which are header.php and footer.php.In header.php file has three link home, product and customer. In xyz folder has product.php and customer.php file.

In index.php, product.php and customer.php i want to include header.php and footer.php.

But i can't right path.

```
<?php include('../../header.php');?>
```

...........

```
<?php include('../../footer.php');?>
```

Please help me, how can i give right path which if i click product link then header.php and footer.php will be load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Directory look something like this:

```
src
->includes
  ->header.php
  ->footer.php
web
->index.php
```

And you want to include the header and the footer in the index.php, do the following:

```
<?php
   //index.php
   include __DIR__.'/../src/includes/header.php';
   echo "foobar";
   include __DIR__.'/../src/includes/footer.php';
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<?php
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.class.php');
?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 2):

Basically i have used like below

```
<?php include_once('../include/header.php');?>
<?php include_once('../include/footer.php');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo realpath('../../header.php');
echo realpath('../../footer.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you can replace

```
 ../../header.php by ../include/header.php and

../../footer.php by ../include/footer.php.
```

then you will get accurate result.